# Indianisation of "Thank You, M'am" written by Langston Hughes

Tags: creative-writing, style, vocabulary

[**Thank You, M'am**](https://www.chino.k12.ca.us/cms/lib/CA01902308/Centricity/Domain/1689/Thank%20You%20%20Ma%20am.pdf)

To Indianise the story, along with the name of the character & place, the story has to be adapted in an Indian context and style. Both style and context are critical here.

Langston Hughes's Thank You, M'am takes place in New York in the 1950s. The characters are unmistakably African-American, but it is not a story about African-Americans. Skin colour is present and well represented in vernacular, but that is not the story's point. It tells us the story of a boy who tries to steal a woman's purse, a woman who tries to make the world a better place from her small corner, a tale of love, trust, kindness, forgiveness and dignity.

So, I need help in conforming the story to the Indian context. How to add an Indian background to this story without changing the central theme?

Comment: What's your question? You need to include enough information to make the problem clear. A link is not enough.

Comment: It seems to me that if you are attempting this, you should be resident in India or at least have spent a lot of time there and be thoroughly familiar with the current culture at the level of the story, otherwise you are doomed to failure. The title, for example, might be "Thank you Memsahib/Memsa'b." Details would be set parallel but in an entirely Indian context. Our hero would not go to a football match but a cricket match, etc.

Comment: When it is not a story about African-Americans; skin colour is present and well represented in vernacular, but that is not the story's point, how far can you take that?

Locations and character names should be trivial; language perhaps less so.

Broadly, what's left but motivation, on individual, familial, social or cultural levels?

Comment: There are many uses of Double-Negative in the character's conversation, which is one of the main characteristics of AAVE(African American Vernacular English) or Black English Vernacular. There are uses of ain't instead of am not, isn't, aren't, haven't, and hasn't.
E.g., "Ain’t you got nobody home to tell you to wash your face?"
“Not with that face, I would not take you nowhere,” said the woman.

The central character of this story is Mrs. Luella Bates Washington Jones. Both the surnames, Jones and Washington, are widely used African-American last names.

Comment: This is going to turn out dire, if the comments are any guide.